# Formatting Objective-C code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I cut and paste Objective-C examples off Safari into Xcode but the formatting gets messed up. I know I can do multiple find and replace for { and \r, but is there a one button fix somewhere? Xcode option / plugin.
TextEdit plugin etc?

Answer: I created an AppleScript in TextWrangler

```
tell application "TextWrangler"
activate
replace "- (" using "\\r- (" searching in text 1 of text document "untitled text" options {search mode:literal, starting at top:true, wrap around:false, backwards:false, case sensitive:false, match words:false, extend selection:false}
select find window
select text 1 of find window
replace ";" using ";\\r" searching in text 1 of text document "untitled text" options {search mode:literal, starting at top:true, wrap around:false, backwards:false, case sensitive:false, match words:false, extend selection:false}
select find window
replace "{" using "{\\r" searching in text 1 of text document "untitled text" options {search mode:literal, starting at top:true, wrap around:false, backwards:false, case sensitive:false, match words:false, extend selection:false}
select find window
replace "//" using "\\r//" searching in text 1 of text document "untitled text" options {search mode:literal, starting at top:true, wrap around:false, backwards:false, case sensitive:false, match words:false, extend selection:false}
end tell
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-indenting in Xcode 4 should solve most formatting issues you might have. However, if you're still not happy with the result, you'll have to go third-party.

I used to change my code formatting quite regularly. I'd go to update some old code, only to find that it was written using deprecated, now unfamiliar, formats.

I've been using [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) to adapt old files to new formats. It's got quite a few options, but is still lacking. However, it should suffice for most cases.

Comment: I used TextWrangler it has option to record an applescript then did find/replace to add \r after } ; and - (

Answer (score 4):

`Control + I` will do some degree of formatting on whatever text  you have selected.

Comment: Control + I or Editor > Structure > Re-Indent only does just that: it will re-indent your selection. And even at that its performance is mediocre.

Answer (score 0):

Configure xcode's preferences such that tab always indents.  Then go with whatever select-all-then-tab gives you for formatting.  It is good enough and doing anything involving formatting that is not automatic is a complete waste of time.